# Change polygon in inset into no fill and only outline

Tags: google-earth-engine, inset-map

I was following widget guide for Google Earth Engine.
Is there any way to change the polygon there (I drew red arrow pointing to what polygon I mean) with only outline and no fill color?

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
// ui.Map
// Make a little map (inset)
var map = ui.Map()

// Make a little map display an inset of the big map
var createInset = function() {
  var bounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds());
  map.centerObject(bounds);
  map.clear();
  map.addLayer(bounds);
};

// Run in once to initialize
createInset();

// Get a new inset map whenever you click on big map
Map.onClick(createInset);

// Display the inset in console
//print(map)
map.style().set('position','bottom-left');
Map.add(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a feature collection from your geometry and style it, setting `fillColor` to a completely transparent rgba color:

```
var bounds = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds())
).style({fillColor: '00000000'});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0cd9828fe2fda7d90599111327ee57b5